# How to add JavaScript event to textarea without having direct access to it?

Tags: javascript, html, events, tags

I'm wondering how to add

```
onblur="hcb.watermark.blur(event)" onfocus="hcb.watermark.focus(event)" style="color: rgb(136, 136, 136);
```

to the following textarea without having direct access to it:

```
<textarea rows="4" id="HCB_textarea" name="content" class="commentbox hcb-shadow-r" onkeypress="hcb.delta(event)"/>
```

Could some additional JS do the job?

Comment: What do you mean by "not having direct access to it"?

Comment: The textarea is created by some external JS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can grab the element using `document.getElementById` and manipulate it from there.

```
var textArea = document.getElementById('HCB_textarea');
textArea.onblur = hcb.watermark.blur;
textArea.onfocus = hcb.watermark.focus;
textArea.style.color = 'rgb(136, 136, 136)';
```

Comment: Is it somehow important where to insert the extra code (before/after the main JS script)?

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery to attach the events, change the style.